# Локальная регистрация, добавление записей через js

Tags: javascript, json, файлы, авторизация, регистрация

необходимо создать регистрацию + авторизацию, добавление комментариев и записей,  интересует вопрос: как лучше реализовать это всё? сохранять данные в куки или через запись в файлы, json?  Был ли у кого-то опыт в подобном. 
Можно конечно сделать регистрацию через сервер, но я совсем новичек в js, интересует самый легкий способ)
Заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: "Был ли у кого-то опыт в подобном." - вряд ли.

Comment: Есть достаточно легкий способ использовать Node + MongoDB + JWT. А локальная "авторизация" я даже не знаю что это. Потому что это, в общем-то, не авторизация. Но, как вариант, можно хранить какие-нибудь значения в localStorage. А авторизацию делать после того, как будет минимальный бэкэнд написан.